Prove that $(\forall k: p^k+1|n^k+1)\implies n=p^a$ where $a$ is odd
I am struggling to prove (or disprove) the following claim:
$$(\forall k: p^k+1|n^k+1)\implies n=p^a$$ where all variables are natural numbers, $p$ is prime and $a$ is odd. I am not entriely sure that it is true but it worked for me so far.
I have tried to modify the condtition to form $ p^k+1|n^k-p^k $ and expanding right side to $ (n-p)(n^{k-1}+n^{k-2}p+\dots+p^{k-1})$ or expressing $n$ as $m(p+1)-1$ for some $m$ (using case $k=1$) but it led nowhere. I have no idea how to handle the infinite number of divisibility conditions and how to get to the fact that $n$ is odd power of $p$.
Any hint would be highly appreciated. Also, I am not expert in number theory.

Are you expecting the proposition to be correct? $3^2+1 \mid 7^2+1$ would seem to provide an easy counterexample.

@EricSnyder The assumption is required to hold for all $k$, not just one $k$.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the second part of the AoPS thread Prove that b is a power of a, and the key lemma used in Post #3 of the AoPS thread Functional Number Theory (Turkey IMO TST 2016 P5).

@GregMartin Ah yes, I see the issue, I read the logic symbols incorrectly.
